# Getting HTML content from php file , after it has been processed

Tags: php, html

I want to get the contents of a php file in HTML. I am using it as a HTML email template but it needs to be populated with dynamic data from my database.

I tried

```
file_get_contents('/emails/orderconfirm.php');
```

But all that does is return the php code before it is processed by the server into HTML.

I'm guessing it's really easy? any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to execute the specific code in your `emails/orderconfirm.php`, you need to [include](http://php.net/include) its content.

Included content are going to be compiled and rendered.
However, You need to get the content as long as you `echo`

That way, you need to use [ob_start()](http://php.net/ob_start) library.

Here's an example of usage :

```
ob_start(); //Init the output buffering
include('emails/orderconfirm.php'); //Include (and compiles) the given file
$emailContent = ob_get_clean(); //Get the buffer and erase it
```

The compiled content is now stored in your `$emailContent` variable and you can use it the way you want.

```
$email->body = $emailContent;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ob_start();
require 'emails/orderconfirm.php';
$email = ob_get_clean();
```

http://php.net/ob_start

Answer (score 0):

You are close, insert the complete URL

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/emails/orderconfirm.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the full http address eg:

```
file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/emails/orderconfirm.php');
```